# A dialog's ViewModel must implement the IDialogAware interface

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm, prism

I am new in c# programming world and I run into this issues when I try to develop app to warn user before any action. I have used dialog box like in html.
On my MainWindowsViewModel, there is method for opening dialog view using dialog service of prism mvvm in wpf. But I am getting the error above when debugging.

```
public void DialogOpen()
    {
        var message = "This is a message that should be shown in the dialog.";
        _dialogService.ShowDialog("DialogView", new DialogParameters($"message={message}"), r =>
        {
            if (r.Result == ButtonResult.None)
                Title = "Result is None";
            else if (r.Result == ButtonResult.OK)
                Title = "Result is OK";
            else if (r.Result == ButtonResult.Cancel)
                Title = "Result is Cancel";
            else
                Title = "I Don't know what you did!?";
        });
```

On my app.xaml.cs

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterSerilog();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ISnackbarMessageQueue, SnackbarMessageQueue>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<IAppConfigurationService, AppConfigurationService>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MainView>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<DialogView, DialogViewModel>();
        
    }
```

On DialogViewModel

```
public class DialogViewModel : BindableBase, IDialogAware
{
    private DelegateCommand<string> _closeDialogCommand;
    public DelegateCommand<string> CloseDialogCommand =>
        _closeDialogCommand ?? (_closeDialogCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(CloseDialog));

    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get { return _message; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _message, value); }
    }
    private string _title = "Notification";
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
    }

    public event Action<IDialogResult> RequestClose;

    protected virtual void CloseDialog(string parameter)
    {
        ButtonResult result = ButtonResult.None;

        if (parameter?.ToLower() == "true")
            result = ButtonResult.OK;
        else if (parameter?.ToLower() == "false")
            result = ButtonResult.Cancel;

        RaiseRequestClose(new DialogResult(result));
    }
    public virtual void RaiseRequestClose(IDialogResult dialogResult)
{
    RequestClose?.Invoke(dialogResult);
}

public virtual bool CanCloseDialog()
{
    return true;
}

public virtual void OnDialogClosed()
{

}

public virtual void OnDialogOpened(IDialogParameters parameters)
{
    Message = parameters.GetValue<string>("message");
}
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways to display a message dialog in a MVVM context without needing to implement a special interface - I presented one methodology in a blog post http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-message-dialogs/

Answer (score 0):

In your dialog's xaml, make sure you have the ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel set to true in the UserControl's header.

See below an example header for reference:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.TestDialog"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
         xmlns:mvvm="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
         
         .....
```